# Use: argument in Icinga 1 service definitions

Tags: nagios, icinga

I see references to a argument `use` in Icinga 1 configuration files e.g. like so:

```
define service {
  use                 check_mk_passive
  host_name           localhost
  service_description General Status
  check_interval      1
  # ...
```

On the other hand, I do not see this argument mentioned in what seems to be the appropriate piece of documentation (section on [service definitions](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga1/latest/en/objectdefinitions.html#service)).

What is the meaning of this argument and where is this documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` is an attribute by which Icinga definitions may refer to templates. [`templates.cfg`](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga1/latest/en/sample-templates.html) contains some examples.